# Team city Build agents

Tags: teamcity, build-agent

We have 2 team city build agents at the moment and we are trying to configure them to run different tests only.

So when running integration tests I want it to use only Agent1 for example.
And all other tests are run on Agent2 except for integration tests. How would i configure this on team city 6.5.1?

Thanks for any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up two build configurations, one for your unit tests and one for your integration tests. You can then assign these to different agents as described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Assigning+Build+Configurations+to+Specific+Build+Agents).